# What is $X\otimes Y$ where $X,Y$ are vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensor-products, tensors

At the end of page 17 in the book General Relativity for Mathematicians of Sachs, Wu, the author writes

> For two vector fields $X$ and $Y$, the tensor fields physically equivalent to $X\otimes Y$ are precisely: $g(X,\cdot)\otimes Y,\ X\otimes g(Y,\cdot)$ and $g(X,\cdot)\otimes g(Y,\cdot)$.

Is I understand, the notation $X\otimes Y$ refers to the tensor product of $X$ and $Y$, but this means $X,\, Y$ must be the tensors over $T_xM$. But in this context, the author presumed that $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields on $M$, which mean output of $X$ and $Y$ is not a scalar, but a vector. So what is the product $X\otimes Y$ considered here ? I'm confused here, hope someone will help me clarify this. Thanks

Comment: Vector fields are contravariant $1$-tensor fields, so this is properly defined.

Comment: If $V,W$ are vector spaces, do you know the meaning of the vector space $V\otimes W$? Assuming you do, $X\otimes Y$ is the mapping which sends each point $x\in M$ to $X(x)\otimes Y(x)\in T_xM\otimes T_xM$, i.e $X\otimes Y$ is a $(2,0)$ tensor field on $M$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo what I know about $(p,q)$-tensor, it is a multilinear map $T:\ (V^*)^p\times V^q\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, and the product of a $(p,q)$-tensor $T$ with a $(r,s)$-tensor $S$ is a $(p+r,q+s)$-tensor $T\otimes S(\cdot,\cdot)= T(\cdot).S(\cdot)$.  Here, with $X$ and $Y$ are vector field $M\longrightarrow TM$, then what is the output of $X\otimes Y$ ?

Comment: Recall that $V\cong V^{**}$. This is the famous double duality isomoprhism in finite-dimensions (google it, I’m not going to explain it here). So, each $v\in V$ can be thought of as an element $\iota(v)\in V^{**}$, i.e as a linear map $\iota(v):V^*\to\Bbb{R}$, i.e a $(1,0)$ tensor. So, $X(x)$ and $Y(x)$ can be thought of as $(1,0)$ tensors on $T_xM$. Now apply the tensor product you know, and do this for each $x\in M$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo oh this is more clear now, many thanks for your helpful answer

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have another querry, why we dont use $V\simeq V^*$ for this case instead $V^{**}$ ?

Comment: @PermQi The use of the term "tensor field" is by no means a mistake. Just like a "vector field behaves like a vector at a point," a tensor field "behaves like a tensor at a point" (this is what peek-a-boo is saying above, but more formally). So when you take the tensor product of two tensor fields, this behaves like the tensor product of two different tensors locally (i.e. at a point).

Comment: In finite dimensions, the vector spaces $V,V^*$ are indeed isomorphic, but there is no *canonical isomorphism* (i.e basis-independent, or without making any other choices). However, $V$ is *canonically isomorphic* to $V^{**}$. All these facts are again well-discussed on the site or any good linear algebra book.

Comment: @peek-a-boo okay, so, about the tensor field $g(X,\cdot)\otimes Y$, how should we understand this tensor ? is it the tensor field that bring any point $x$ to the tensor $g\big(X(x),\cdot\big)\otimes Y(x) $ or it is the tensor field that take $x$ to the tensor $g\big(X,x\big)\otimes Y $ ?

Comment: The first. The second doesn’t even make sense.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have another question : if $(M,g)$ is a pseudo Riemannian manifold with metric tensor $g$, and $X,Y:\ M\longrightarrow TM,\ p\longmapsto X_p, Y_p\in TM_p$, then as we discuss above, the product tensor $X\otimes Y$ is understand as
\begin{align}
X_p\otimes Y_p:\ TM_p^{^{\ast}}\times TM_p^{^{\ast}} &\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\newline (u,v)&\longmapsto X_p\otimes Y_p(u,v)=X_p(u)Y_p(v).
\end{align}
But, is it the same thing with this tensor 
\begin{align}
g(X,Y):\ M&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\newline p&\longmapsto g(X,Y)(p)=g_p(X,Y)=\big<X_p,Y_p\big>_p
\end{align}
?

Comment: They’re obviously not equal. One is a $(2,0)$ tensor field on $M$, the other is a smooth real-valued function on $M$ (i.e a $(0,0)$- tensor field on $M$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I mean if they could be the same in their real value, $$X_p\otimes Y_p(u,v)=\big<X_p,Y_p\big>_p $$ ?

Comment: Sure you could cook up some weird examples to make those numbers equal (e.g $X=Y=0$ or $X,Y$ orthogonal and $(u,v)=(0,0)$ so both sides of the equation vanish), but this isn’t really a good way to think about such things. They’re different rank tensor fields, so best to not mix them up.